# Windows Server 2022 Core: how to change default keyboard layout for all users (also login screen)

Tags: registry, keyboard-layout, windows-server-2022

I have a Server with Windows Server 2022 Core Standard and I set the language and time to US but the keyboard layout to German during installation.

However the keyboard layout is US by default for all users also on the login screen.
Does anyone know how to adjust?

What I have tried so far:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload** -> name:1, value:"00000407"
Works only for current user and not for login screen.

**HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload** -> name:1, value:"00000407"
Changes back to "00000409" after new logout and login.

Comment: Same behavior on Windows Server 2019 Standard.

Comment: Once you use the "Copy settings" button from "Administrative language settings", further changes to `HKU:\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload` seem to persist. So until then, these keys seem to pull defaults from somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a qick way to change the keyboard layout to a German keyboard using powershell in **Server Core**:

```
PS C:\> Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList "de-DE"
```

Comment: This affects the current user only.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows Server 2022, the cmdlet [`Copy-UserInternationalSettingsToSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/copy-userinternationalsettingstosystem?view=windowsserver2022-ps) is available now. You can use this cmdlet to copy the *Diplay Language*, *Input Language*, *Format* and *Location* settings of your current user (with administrative privileges) to the system defaults.

I assume that you also need the german keyboard layout on the welcome screen, so that you can input your passwords correctly. Therefore, call `Copy-UserInternationalSettingsToSystem` with both of its switches:

```
Copy-UserInternationalSettingsToSystem -WelcomeScreen $True -NewUser $True
```

Comment: `Copy-UserInternationalSettingsToSystem` is not available on **Server Core** as OP asked about.

Comment: @IODEV About which login screen is OP talking if he really means Server Core?

Comment: IMO I think it's pretty obvious with both the title `Windows Server 2022 *Core*:..` and the description `I have a Server with Windows Server 2022 *Core*...`